# old instance of prototype bean spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

my problem is i need to find existing instance of prototype bean [it is thread actually]. multiple instance of particular bean exists anytime of application.

Another master thread which manages bunch of such threads if any of thread is not completed in time . master thread should kill them .

PrototypeBean someBean=applicationContext.getBean(PrototypeBean.class);

will create another instance of bean [which i do not want]. not sure how to get existing instance of bean . is there any way spring can give me list of all instances of Bean for any class.

let me know if you require any more information.

Comment: AFAIK, spring will only help you with the creation of objects, the container isn't "holding" them (singletons are exceptional by their nature). I think you'll have to have some kind of "manager" object which will hold all of the required instances.

Answer (score 2):

You could register that prototype beans in an single scoped bean after creation.

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Component
public class YourPrototypeTypeBean() {
    @Autowired
    private FinderBean finderBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        finderBean.register(this);
    }
}

@Service
public class FinderBean {
     private Set<YourPrototypeTypeBean> allYourPrototypeTypeBeans = new HashSet<>;

     public void register(YourPrototypeTypeBean beanToRegister) {
          this.allYourPrototypeTypeBeans.add(beanToRegister)
     }
}
```

If you need this in an multi threaded environment, you have to synchronize   the access to the set or use a thread save variant!

Comment: The other possible way to register your prototype (or any other kind) bean is to implement Spring's InitializingBean interface - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376750/5632321