# SpringBoot retrieve existing prototype beans

Tags: spring-boot, prototype, spring-bean

As my title, is there a way to retrieve those existing prototype bean?
I have a prototype bean called "A", and called applicationContext.getBean() method 10 times to create 10 instances. **There is no variable referring to those instances.**

Ways I have tried but doesn't work:

1.autowiring a list of A as below:

```
@autowired
List<A> as;
```

this can only get the last instance I created.

2. if I using beanFactory to get bean, it will just create a new instance A.

Comment: if you want to get the same bean then why you need prototype ?

Comment: This is a runnable class to retrieve data. There can be multi threads receiving data.

Answer (score 1):

these beans will not be managed by spring container, you must do it by yourself, so you should create a collection to store them, just implements **InitializingBean** to store it

```
public class A implements InitializingBean {
    public static final List<A> STORES = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        A.STORES.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to see if I could have access those beans by spring container. If not, I will create reference to maintain those instances.